# Unable to bind click event in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, underscore.js

I can't seem to bind a click event to an action in the snippet below. Any ideas?

```
var SelectView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: "#select-template",
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  events: {
    "click .placeholder": "optionsDropdown",
  },
  render: function() {
    context = {className: this.className, options: this.model.get("options"), placeholder: this.model.get("placeholder")};
    $(this.el).html(getHTML(this.template, context));
  },
  optionsDropdown: function() { 
    alert("Hello");
  },
});
```

Comment: Does it work if in your `initialize` method you do `this.$el.on("click", this.optionsDropdown);`?

Comment: @Mash: No, I just tried that. For some reason I can't hook into it.

Comment: you are missing a target element (el) i made changes to my answer and added a working fiddle

Comment: How does data in your model look like ? I doubt this line `className: this.className`  . I don't see the `className` variable anywhere in the view defnition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this line

```
className: this.className
```

I don't see the className variable anywhere in the view definition

```
  var SelectView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.className = 'placeholder';
    },
    events: {
        "click .placeholder": "optionsDropdown",
    },
    render: function () {
        context = {
            className: this.className,
            options: this.model.get("options"),
            placeholder: this.model.get("placeholder")
        };
        var template = _.template( $("#select-template").html(), context );

        this.$el.html(template);
    },
    optionsDropdown: function () {
        alert("Hello");
    },
});

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var newModel = new Model({
    'options' : 'Hello',
    'placeholder' : 'Type your name'
});

var newView = new SelectView({model : newModel});
newView.render();
$('.container').append(newView.el);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGeJd/3/)**

You are binding the `click` event for the `class="placeholder"` which is supposed to be in the template. Once you define that it should work provided that you have the element with that class in your template.

**[Calling render from initialize](http://jsfiddle.net/FGeJd/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can have a DOM element binded to the handler e.g., `"click li":"optionsDropDown"`

edit: you are missing the target element.. heres a working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/FGeJd/

Comment: This is incorrect. "Omitting the selector causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (this.el)" - [Backbone Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)

Comment: By default `el` will be a div, so that should not be a problem

Comment: yeah but it'l be an orphan until you insert it into the DOM and you need to do something like `$('#selection-parent').html(new SelectView().render().el);`.. passing in an `el` like `new SelectView({el: '#selection'})` would be a better approach than having an orphan div

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a selector in the event definition. It should be something like this (assuming the input id is optionsId):

```
events : {
    "click #optionsId": "optionsDropDown"
}
```

Comment: We had the selector in there – I was trying it without just for kicks. Doesn't work either way.

Comment: Try calling render() from outside the view itself, ie from the router. Also, render() is supposed to return `this`.

Comment: In the router you are supposed to have something like this:


`this.elms['page-content'].html(view.render().el);`